# Get tensor by name - but in TF2

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I've recently moved to TF2 (a bit late to the party, I know), and there's one piece of functionality that I haven't been able to find its TF2 equivalent; namely `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name()`.
I'm aware of `tf.compat.v1`, but for various reasons this doesn't work for me.
Is there some way to get a tensor based on its name in TF2?
For instance, assuming the tutorial model for simplicity:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

  def call(self, inputs):
    # Lots of stuff going on, and many named tensors of different sorts
    # Assume a tensor of name "my_happy_tensor:0" exists
    # How do I get a handle on that tensor only based on its name??
    # Just for the record, using tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node returns an empty list, 
    # so I don't seem to be able to get the right graph either? Not sure that's related...
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    return self.dense2(x)

model = MyModel()
```

So my question is: "In the above example code, what line would I put in place that could get me a tensor by its name?"